# How to measure number / time of edits by my editors

Tags: nodes

I am looking for a module or an approach or some tips on how to measure the editing activity of my editing team within my Drupal site.  I'm ideally looking for a report or dashboard that shows me how many edits, how much time, or how many words have been entered into the system on a weekly basis, rather like an asset league.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Have you checked built-in Revisions ? Is it not sufficient?

Comment: Time may be tricky. Number, as @AgA says, may be obtained from revisions, but I don't think time is stored anywhere.

Comment: Thanks folks, I reckon I need the UserPoints module:  https://drupal.org/project/userpoints